# VS 2022 - Can I change Assembly Name in Click Once

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I wanted to publish application in UAT and PROD version, but is it possible for me to set Assembly name that is set based on Publishing Profile (Click Once). Or do I have to change Assembly name with each publish on .csproj depending if i want to push UAT or PROD version?

This is project developed only by me, with no services available i publish them thru shared drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post as below.

Hi, Krzysztof Mastalerz. Assembly name can't be changed via ClickOnce in Visual Studio2022. You could change the assembly name when running two different versions, if you have to change the assembly name then you will have to uninstall and reinstall the application. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007262/is-there-a-way-to-rename-a-deployed-clickonce-application) for more details .

Comment: I'll accept it as it's currently true.